# setting bounce email for phpmailer

Tags: php

I am new to programming. I am trying to send email via PHPmailer. I requires any reply from user to go to email A while any bounce mail go to email B.

I have successfully in implementing the reply-to functions but unable to get the bounce mail to work. This is a snippet of my code:

```
$boardcastmail->AddAddress('target@usermail.org', 'target user');
$boardcastmail->AddReplyTo('repl-to-me@tuta.io', 'Email for reply to');
$boardcastmail->SetFrom('mrloong@officialmail.com', 'From Name and Email');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much. f{rwhughoidfc2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

`$boardcastmail->Sender = 'bounces@example.com';`

Where 'bounces@example.com' is the return-path (bounce).